# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Wikipedia'

Tags: python, wikipedia

При попытке использовать модуль wikipedia интерпретатор говорит о том, что модуля с таким именем нет. Но при проверке в командной строке с помощью pip list чётко видно что установлен модуль wikipedia v.1.4.0

Comment: Значит запускаете не тем интерпретатором или не в том окружении, для которого установили пакет. Укажите как конкретно запускаете (через IDE, через какое IDE, или из командной строки), используете ли виртуальное окружение, установлено ли несколько интерпретаторов.

Comment: Как узнать для какого окружения был установлен пакет? Использую Thonny,также установлен SublimeText

Comment: а у вас активировано виртуальное окружение?